Pyinstaller not in path
The command prompt is showing me that pyinstaller is not a valid command when I try to convert .py to .exe. I am using the latest python version: 3.12.4 I want to add it to path but can't figure out how.
> pyinstaller youtube.py --onefile
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I tried using other methods such as Nuitka but those also don't work. Pyinstaller seems like the right option. I found a couple of similar issues on Stack Overflow but they were pycharm focused or they were related to pyinstaller not being installed. But I have already installed pyinstaller. I can't figure out how to put it in path.

What do you mean you can't figure out how to put it in path?

Also, Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I cant figure out which path to put in the env variables. Cause I know its located in C:/users/user/appdata folder somewhere, I found the pyinstaller folder but I cant find any documentation or stuff online on which path to put in the variables list.

Try python -m PyInstaller. It's not dependent on PATH, and it's more reliable when you're using different environments.

I'm getting , no module named PyInstaller . Tried changing the indentation , maybe its all small letters like 'pyinstaller' but that didnt work either

Have you installed pyinstaller, ie something like pip install pyinstaller?

We have an imperial ton of questions about how to troubleshoot your PATH. The information we need is to see where exactly pyinstaller.exe is installed, and what your current PATH looks like. But then with those details, this will be a trivial duplicate of many, many existing questions.

My pyinstaller is already installed using pip as If I run the command , I receive a prompt in the terminal requirement already satisfied . The only problem is I am not able to use Pyinstaller commands in the terminal
